# Advanced Custom Fields - Get value in other plugin file

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF plugin and i have a dropdown added to users who have a specific role. The dropdown contains the values Yes and No. That value i need to get in an other plugin, but i couldn't get it to work...

This is what is have:

```
$woonfield = get_field_object('wooncheck');
$woonvalue = get_field('wooncheck');
$woonlabel = $woonfield['choices'][ $woonvalue ];

<?php echo $woonvalue ?>
```

Do I need to put the current user ID somewhere or something else? I really have no idea anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/), if you're not getting values from posts, you need to prepend the ID. For users that needs to be `user_`

```
$id = ...;
get_field('wooncheck', 'user_' . $id);
```

Comment: Great! That works :)